# Session field is None

Tags: reactjs, azure-devops, react-router, flask-cors

I have hosted a rest API written in Flask in one domain and my react app in another domain in azure app services. I can successfully log into the system using a username and password. However, when I try to hit an endpoint, I get `None` for the username attribute (locally everything is working without any issues).

```
def login_required( f ):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap( *args, **kwargs ):
        project_owner = session.get( 'username' )
        if project_owner is None:            
            logging.error( ERROR_MSG.LOGIN_ERROR_MSG )
            return response.cannot_process_redirect( ERROR_MSG.LOGIN_ERROR_MSG, '/' )
        else:
            return f( *args, **kwargs )
    return wrap
```

I think I have applied the correct CORS policies but I cannot get it to work. Applied CORS configurations are as below.

```
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY'] = False
CORS( app, supports_credentials = True, resources = {r"/api/*": {"origins": "http://domainA.net"}} )
```

And the fetch request of the endpoint looks like below.

```
export function getUsers() {
    const url = 'users/'
    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
      credentials: 'include'
    };
    return ( dispatch ) => {
    return fetchReq( requestOptions, url ).then( ([response, json]) => {
        // Do something
    } )
  }
}
```

Also in Azure app service, `domainA` is added to the allowed origin list in `domainB`.

[image]

If I use Postman, I can use endpoints without any issues. One thing I noticed is in my request and response session value strings are different. Below is a screenshot of request-response headers.

Any ideas?
[image: Request-Response Headers]

Comment: Nothing in the question as currently written indicates any problem related to CORS. If there were a CORS problem, the browser would be logging an error message in the devtools console that specifically mentions CORS.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I just want to make sure that I have set the CORS policies correct for cross-domain communication. Also to give some ideas to see different session strings in request and response headers. Currently, I'm stuck as I have explored all the possibilities I can think of.

Comment: If you didn’t have the CORS policies for cross-domain communication set correctly, the way you’d know is that the browser would report an error in the devtools console. So if the browser doesn’t report any such errors, then you know you have the CORS policies set correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around for many days I found out that I need to add `credentials: 'include'` to my fetch request so the that the browser will send cookie with cross-origin requests (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials). So my final CORS configuration in Flask app is below.

```
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE'] = True
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY'] = True
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE'] = 'None'
CORS( app, resources = {r"/api/*": {"origins": ["http://localhost:3000", "<Domains that are allowed to do cross origin requests>"],
```